# how to properly identify the link for img src in wp

Tags: html, wordpress

```
<img src="/wp-content/themes/charitas-lite/images/flag_150.gif">
```

Here is the code for displaying the image. I am receiving the console error

> GET http://domain.org/wp-content/themes/charitas-lite/images/flag_150.gif 404 (Not Found)

Anyone here know how to do it? I am having a hard time displaying an image since I am going to put it fixed at the top of my page...

Screenshot showing that the image is really there. Proof that the image is there..

[image]

Comment: Is WordPress installed in the document root? Are you sure the image is actually there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/image.jpg">
```

Comment: r u sure image is there

Comment: can you please paste your image in image folder of your theme

Comment: i copy pasted the image again to make it work, but yes your code helped the code work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123600/discussion-between-bansal-kapil-and-beldion-bryan-balanan).